# Google login onsuccess callback isn't running all the time

Tags: angular, google-signin

I've been able to authenticate a user via Google's login API but it seems that the success function isn't always successfully running.

In my login component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.nav.hide();
    this.createLoginForm();
    // get redirect url from authguard
    this.redirectUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['redirectUrl'] || '/';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.googleInit();
  }


  // social login - Google
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

  googleInit() {
    let that = this;

    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
      that.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: that.config.googleClientId,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });

      that.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
    })
  }

  attachSignin(element) {
    let that = this;
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      function(googleUser) {
        let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
        let socialUser = that.prepareSocialUser(googleUser);
        that.googleLogin(socialUser);


        // <--- Inconsistencies start here --->
        // display alert
        that.alertService.success('Logged in as ' + profile.getEmail(), true, 3000);
        // redirect to previous url
        that.router.navigate([that.redirectUrl]);
        // reveal nav
        that.nav.show();
        // <--- End of inconsistencies --->


      }, function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      });
  }

  prepareSocialUser(googleUser): SocialUser {

    const socialUser: SocialUser = {
      access_token: googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token
    }

    return socialUser

  }

  googleLogin(socialUser: SocialUser) {
    this.userService.googleLogin(socialUser)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // save to session
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

1. The alert service should be called to display an alert notifying the user of his successful login attempt (after redirecting to the landing page)
2. The navbar is hidden on the login page, so when a user successfully logs in via Google, he will be redirected back to the landing page, where the navbar will be visible again via a navbar service

The redirection is working fine 100% of the time, however currently I can't wrap my head around why sometimes the alert doesn't show, and the navbar sometimes doesn't show itself again. I've tried placing `console.log` in different areas of the services to debug, but they seem to indicate that the services are running as they should - e.g. the alerts are 'showing' but they don't appear.

I'm quite confused right now so I'm not sure if this is sufficient info for you Angular experts out there to assist! Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction, will be happy to provide more code if required.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @jarguez01this was quite some time ago so I can't really remember the details, but I believe the solution was to run it within NgZone